# When I want to open my react application this comes up. (npm start)

Tags: npm-start

First this was a problem:

> Error: Cannot find module 'merge-stream'

So I installed merge-stream and now this...
I use `npm start` to open my react app.

```
my-app@0.1.0 start
react-scripts start
```

> node:internal/fs/utils:348
> throw err;
> ^
>
> Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, read
> at Object.readSync (node:fs:748:3)
> at tryReadSync (node:fs:448:20)
> at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:486:19)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:18)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
> at Object. (...\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js:22:31)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14) {   errno: -4094,   syscall: 'read',   code: 'UNKNOWN' }

I expect it working :)